# assigning sequentially increasing group number to chunks of data with same indicator value in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

Given a date frame:

```
set.seed(123)
data.frame("var1" = runif(10),
           "indicator" = c(rep(1,2),rep(0,2), rep(1,2), rep(0,2), rep(1,2)))
       
 var1           indicator
1  0.8895393         1
2  0.6928034         1
3  0.6405068         0
4  0.9942698         0
5  0.6557058         1
6  0.7085305         1
7  0.5440660         0
8  0.5941420         0
9  0.2891597         1
10 0.1471136         1
```

How can I make it so that the first group of ones in the "indicator" column are assigned "1", the second chunk of ones assigned "2" etc.?

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
     var1        indicator  new_col
1  0.96302423         1       1
2  0.90229905         1       1
3  0.69070528         0       0
4  0.79546742         0       0
5  0.02461368         1       2
6  0.47779597         1       2
7  0.75845954         0       0
8  0.21640794         0       0
9  0.31818101         1       3
10 0.23162579         1       3
```

Looking for a tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, it can be done with `rle`

```
dat$new_col <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(dat$indicator), 
     {values[values == 1] <- seq_len(sum(values))}))
```

-output

```
> dat
        var1 indicator new_col
1  0.2875775         1       1
2  0.7883051         1       1
3  0.4089769         0       0
4  0.8830174         0       0
5  0.9404673         1       2
6  0.0455565         1       2
7  0.5281055         0       0
8  0.8924190         0       0
9  0.5514350         1       3
10 0.4566147         1       3
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dat %>%
   mutate(new_col = rleid(indicator) * indicator,
   new_col = match(new_col, unique(new_col[new_col != 0]), nomatch = 0))
```

-output

```
        var1 indicator new_col
1  0.2875775         1       1
2  0.7883051         1       1
3  0.4089769         0       0
4  0.8830174         0       0
5  0.9404673         1       2
6  0.0455565         1       2
7  0.5281055         0       0
8  0.8924190         0       0
9  0.5514350         1       3
10 0.4566147         1       3
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
setDT(dat)[, new_col := fcoalesce(as.integer(factor(rleid(indicator) * 
            NA^!indicator)), 0L)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cumsum`:

```r
df$v <- with(df, cumsum(indicator == 1 & dplyr::lag(indicator == 0, default = 1)))
df$v[df$indicator == 0] <- 0

        var1 indicator v
1  0.2875775         1 1
2  0.7883051         1 1
3  0.4089769         0 0
4  0.8830174         0 0
5  0.9404673         1 2
6  0.0455565         1 2
7  0.5281055         0 0
8  0.8924190         0 0
9  0.5514350         1 3
10 0.4566147         1 3
```